# Using a variable as the REGEXP in `query-replace-regexp`

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp

I know, Emacs allows calling ELisp while replacing a text with a regex, aka `C-M-%`, which is bound to `query-replace-regexp`. I'm trying to make use of that to store an unwieldy regexp as a variable, so instead of writing it out every time, I could just extract it from a variable.

For the sake of simplification, in the testcase here I'm using just a text, so no backslashes are involved:

```lisp
(setq foo "text")
```

Text is:

```
text text
```

Here's what I tried as the REGEXP in `query-replace-regexp`:

- `\,foo`
- `\,'foo`
- `\,(eval 'foo)`
- `\,(eval foo)`

None of those work for me. How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you mean you want to enter the variable name into the interactive prompt after pressing `C-M-%`?

Comment: @choroba correct

Comment: You can write a new function that wraps `query-replace-regexp` and asks for a variable to insert.

Comment: @choroba well, I might indeed, but that sounds like an overkill to me. I'd have to design it in such way so I could insert another text besides just the variable *(because I might want to add more pattern besides the regex the variable stores)*; and then I'd also have either think whether I can make it a full-featured replacement for `query-replace-regexp` *(so I wouldn't have to make it a separate keybind)*, or whether I'd prefer to just keep it on a separate keybind… To me personally that sounds like too much of a hassle.

Comment: You can use the `X` option of `interactive` to ask for a List expression and evaluate it.

Comment: In reading the doc of `query-replace-regexp`, it mentions the `\,` syntax in the *replacement text* part, but not in the *regex* part. So AFAICT, you cannot do what you want: you'd have to write your own souped-up version of `query-replace-regexp` as @choroba suggests.

Comment: @NickD oh, I see, now that makes sense. You can post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reading the doc of `query-replace-regexp`, it mentions the `\,` syntax in the *replacement text* part, but not in the *regex part*:

> In interactive calls, the replacement text can contain ‘,’
> followed by a Lisp expression.

So AFAICT, you cannot do what you want interactively: you'd have to write your own souped-up version of `query-replace-regexp` as @choroba suggests in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

```
M-: (query-replace-regexp foo "bar") RET
```

Comment: Well, yeah, that might work too. ⁺¹.